# R: Casting a character column without aggregation

Tags: r, reshape2

I want to transpose this data frame from

```
Cat Group Rank 
229    A     1
229    C     2
230    B     1
230    E     2
231    F     1
231    D     2
..   ..    ..
```

and make it look like

```
Cat    1     2 
229    A     C
230    B     E
231    F     D
 ..    ..    ..
```

I've used `dcast` from `reshape2`

`Table<- dcast(Table, Cat ~ Rank , value.var = 'Group')`

but I get the following when executing:
`Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length`

and the data frame converts to

```
Cat    1     2 
229    1     1
230    1     1
231    1     1
 ..    ..    ..
```

Any ideas how can I resolve this?

Comment: We may need a sequence column i.e. `library(data.table);dcast(setDT(Rank2), Cat + rowid(Rank) ~ Rank, value.var = 'Group')`

Comment: `library(tidyverse); df %>%
  spread(Rank, Group)` ?

Comment: Note that duplicates are issue for `tidyverse` or in other verses

Comment: @Ronak I get `Error in spread(., rank, Group) : could not find function "spread"`

Comment: `spread` is a function in the `tidyr` package which should be loaded with `library(tidyverse)` so make sure you have the latest tidyverse installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a sequence column for the duplicates and it should work

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(Rank2), Cat + rowid(Rank) ~ Rank, value.var = 'Group')
```